# Lazy-init an array with multi-threaded readers: is it safe without barriers or atomics?

Tags: c, x86, thread-safety, memory-barriers, memory-model

I've been having an implementation discussion where the idea that a CPU can choose to completely reorder the storing of memory has come up.

I was initializing a static array in C using code similar to:

```
static int array[10];
static int array_initialized = 0;

void initialize () {

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    ...
    array_initialized = -1;

}
```

and it is used later similar to:

```
int get_index(int index) {
    if (!array_initialized) initialize();
    if (index < 0 || index > 9) return -1;
    return array[index];
}
```

is it possible for the CPU to reorder memory access in a multi-core intel architecture (or other architecture) such that it sets `array_initialized` before the `initialize` function has finished setting the array elements? or so that another execution thread can see `array_initialized` as non-zero before the entire array has been initialized in its view of the memory?

Comment: (The `[memory-order]` tag is a synonym for `[memory-barriers]`, for some reason; that's why I added it; I know you're asking about the no-barriers case with non-atomic variables.)

Comment: Your code seems to return -1 for all imaginable valid indexes. It only returns the value found in the array at the given index, if that is guaranteed to access outside of the array. Or am I misreading something?

Comment: @PeterCordes - thanks. i didn't know about that tag.

Comment: @Yunnosch - it's a dumb example i wrote on the fly and inverted the test. am fixing now, but the question isn't really affected. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The x86 CPU architecture does not allow reordering these memory writes. However, the compiler is free to, in the absence of any barriers. Are you really interested in the defined behavior of the C code, or are you just using C code as pseudo-code to represent the order of actual CPU instructions?

Comment: @prl - i'm interested in whether the code, as written, can be changed. it seems that if the compiler can arbitrarily change the order of code then what the language specifies is not deterministic. so if x86 cannot reorder the writes i'm interested in the defined behavior of a C compiler. i honestly didn't consider that the c compiler could change the sequence of what my code specified.

Answer (score 4):

TL:DR: to make lazy-init safe if you don't do it before starting multiple threads, you need an `_Atomic` flag.

---

> is it possible for **the CPU** to reorder memory access in a multi-core Intel (**x86**) architecture

No, such reordering is possible at compile time only.  x86 asm effectively has acquire/release semantics for normal loads/stores.  (seq_cst + a store buffer with store forwarding).

https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/

> (or other architecture)

Yes, most other ISAs have a weaker asm memory model that does allow StoreStore reordering and LoadLoad reordering.  (Effectively `memory_order_relaxed`, or sort of like `memory_order_consume` on ISAs other than Alpha AXP, but compilers don't try to maintain data dependencies.)

---

**None of this really matters from C because the C memory model is very weak, allowing compile-time reordering** and simultaneous read/write or write+write of any object is data-race UB.

Data Race UB is what lets a compiler keep `static` variables in registers for the life of a function / inside a loop when compiling for "normal" ISAs.

**Having 2 threads run this function is C data-race UB if `array_initialized` isn't already set before either of them run**.  (e.g. by having the main thread run it once before starting any more threads).  And remove the `array_initialized` flag entirely, unless you have a use for the lazy-init feature before starting any more threads.

It's 100% safe for a single thread, regardless of how many other threads are running: the C programming model guarantees that a single thread always sees its own operations in program order.  (Just like asm for all normal ISAs; other than explicit parallelism in ISAs like Itanium, you always see your own operations in order.  It's only other threads seeing your operations where things get weird).

Starting a new thread is (I think) always a "full barrier", or in C terms "synchronizes with" the new thread.  Stuff in the new thread can't happen before anything in the parent thread.  So just calling `get_index` once from the main thread makes it safe with no further barriers for other threads to run `get_index` after that.

---

#### You could make lazy init thread-safe with an `_Atomic` flag

**This is similar to what gcc does for function-local `static` variables with non-constant initializers**.  Check out the code-gen for that if you're curious: a read-only check of an already-init flag and then a call to an init function that makes sure only one thread runs the initializer.

This requires an `acquire` load in the fast-path for the already-initialized state.  That's free on x86 and SPARC-TSO (same asm as a normal load), but not on weaker ISAs.  AArch64 has an acquire load instruction, other ISAs need some barrier instructions.

Turn your `array_initialized` flag into a 3-state `_Atomic` variable:

- init not started  (e.g. `init == 0`).  Check for this with an `acquire` load.
- init started but not finished (e.g. `init == -1`)
- init finished (e.g. `init == 1`)

You can leave `static int array[10];` itself non-`atomic` by **making sure exactly 1 thread "claims" responsibility for doing the init,** using `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` (which will succeed for exactly one thread).  And then have other threads spin-wait for the `INIT_FINISHED` state.

Using initial state == 0 lets it be in the BSS, hopefully next to the data.  Otherwise we might prefer `INIT_FINISHED=0` for ISAs where branching on an `int` from memory being (non)zero is slightly more efficient than other numbers.  (e.g. AArch64 `cbnz`, MIPS `bne $reg, $zero`).

We could get the best of both worlds (cheapest possible fast-path for the already-init case) while still having the flag in the BSS:  Have the main thread write it with `INIT_NOTSTARTED = -1` before starting any more threads.

Having the flag next to the array is helpful for a small array where the flag is probably in the same cache line as the data we want to index.  Or at least the same 4k page.

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#ifdef __x86_64__
#include <immintrin.h>
#define SPINLOOP_BODY  _mm_pause()
#else
#define SPINLOOP_BODY  /**/
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define unlikely(expr) __builtin_expect(!!(expr), 0)
#define likely(expr) __builtin_expect(!!(expr), 1)
#define NOINLINE __attribute__((noinline))
#else 
#define unlikely(expr) (expr)
#define likely(expr) (expr)
#define NOINLINE /**/
#endif

enum init_states {
 INIT_NOTSTARTED = 0,
 INIT_STARTED = -1,
 INIT_FINISHED = 1   // optional: make this 0 to speed up the fast-path on some ISAs, and store an INIT_NOTSTARTED before the first call
};

static int array[10];
static _Atomic int array_initialized = INIT_NOTSTARTED;

// called either before or during init.
// One thread claims responsibility for doing the init, others spin-wait
NOINLINE    // this is rare, make sure it doesn't bloat the fast-path
void initialize(void) {
    bool winner = false;
    // check read-only if another thread has already claimed init
    if (array_initialized == INIT_NOTSTARTED) {
        int expected = INIT_NOTSTARTED;
        winner = atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&array_initialized, &expected, INIT_STARTED);
        // seq_cst memory order is fine.  Weaker might be ok but it only has to run once
    }

    if (winner) {
        array[0] = 1;
        // ...
        atomic_store_explicit(&array_initialized, INIT_FINISHED, memory_order_release);
    } else {
         // spin-wait for the winner in other threads
         // yield();  optional.
         // Or use some kind of mutex or condition var if init is really slow

         // otherwise just spin on a seq_cst load.  (Or acquire is fine.)
         while(array_initialized != INIT_FINISHED)
             SPINLOOP_BODY;   // x86 only

         // winner's release store syncs with our load:
         // array[] stores Happened Before this point so we can read it without UB
    }

}

int get_index(int index) {
    // atomic acquire load is fine, doesn't need seq_cst.  Cheaper than seq_cst on PowerPC
    if (unlikely(atomic_load_explicit(&array_initialized, memory_order_acquire) != INIT_FINISHED))
        initialize();
    if (unlikely(index < 0 || index > 9)) return -1;
    return array[index];
}
```

This does compile to correct-looking and efficient [asm on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/RJsQsi).  Without `unlikely()` macros, gcc/clang think that at least the stand-alone version of `get_index` has `initialize()` and/or `return -1` as the most likely fast-path.

And compilers wanted to inline the init function, which would be silly because it only runs once per thread at most.  Hopefully profile-guided optimization would correct that.

Comment: If the size of the array is sufficiently large, the latency of the first invocation to `get_index` may be too high, even though only a single array element may be needed. This latency can be significantly reduced by logically partitioning the array into multiple segments, where each segment has an initialization state. A thread only has to initialize the segment in which the target index exists. This also allows the array to be initialized in parallel. Alternatively, the array could be preemptively initialized (in a dedicated thread) when the program starts. A hybrid design is possible also.

Comment: @HadiBrais: yup, I was thinking some of that.  Init before starting multiple threads, or multi-threaded non-lazy init as the first thing threads do before any calls to `get_index`, is obviously best for the steady state fast-path, removing any flag check.  (I guess use a condition var or spin-loop as an all-thread barrier to make sure all threads finish init before any proceed past that point.)